# Match value in column within a range of another column on the same dataframe and return corresponding row

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to find the best way to get the value of column Y which falls in the range of column Z and return the  corresponding row.

For instance, consider A in column X, the value in Y is 25 so it falls between 20 and 30 so the corresponding value in W is 2.

```
## example dataframe
df <- data.frame(X=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 Y=c(25,25,25,25,35,35,35,15,15,15),
                 Z=c(10,20,30,40,10,20,30,10,20,30),
                 w=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3))

#desired dataframe
df2 <- data.frame(X=c("A","B","C"),
                  Y=c(25,35,15),
                  Z=c(20,30,10),
                  w=c(2,3,1))
```

---

The problem needs a fix. Let´s say D has a value Y (5) less than min Z (10) in this case it would get 0. How can that be accomplished ?

```
df <- data.frame(X=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C","D","D","D"),
                 Y=c(25,25,25,25,35,35,35,15,15,15,5,5,5),
                 Z=c(10,20,30,40,10,20,30,10,20,30,10,20,30),
                 w=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))

df2 <- data.frame(X=c("A","B","C","D"),
                  Y=c(25,35,15,5),
                  Z=c(20,30,10,0),
                  w=c(2,3,1,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this (depending on the logic).  One way is to group by 'X', get the row with the `min`imum `abs`olute difference between 'Z' and 'Y'.  Note that for 'B' elements in 'X', the row selected is the last row where we don't know if the Y will be in range or not

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(X) %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(Z - Y))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  X         Y     Z     w
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        25    20     2
2 B        35    30     3
3 C        15    10     1
```

---

Or another option is to create a `lead` column after grouping by 'X', create a logical vector in `filter` and use `if/else` to return cases where there is no upper range i.e. for 'B'

```
df %>% 
   group_by(X) %>%
   mutate(Z1 = lead(Z, default = last(Z))) %>% 
   filter({tmp <- Y > Z & Y <Z1
     if(any(tmp)) tmp else row_number() == n()
    }) %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    select(-Z1)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. The second solution solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps we can try the `data.table` like below

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[findInterval(Y, Z) == seq_along(w)], X]
   X  Y  Z w
1: A 25 20 2
2: B 35 30 3
3: C 15 10 1
```